# Why am I getting PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values?

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors

I am writing code in a stored procedure to inserting records into a table. But I keep getting this error:

```
[Error] ORA-00947 (198: 17): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Stuck on this for a long time, and everything looking fine after taking the procedure apart piece by piece, I've decided to comment out everything in procedure except for one part that is only selecting null values and inserting them into the table, with the exact same amount of fields as there are in the table. The procedure completely stripped out to see if anything simply works looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_Proc
(
    Date                  DATE
)
AS
BEGIN 


    INSERT INTO test_table

    SELECT
        null as column1,
        null as column2,
        null as column3
    FROM dual;

    COMMIT;

END Test_Proc;
/
```

Yet, somehow I still get the same error. The amount of columns is ***exactly*** the same as in the table - three columns. How is it possible that I am still getting this error?

Comment: show your `test_table` schema?

Comment: Your error appears to reference a line number 198.  The code you posted obviously doesn't have 198 lines.  Are you sure that the error actually references this `insert` statement?  It's always a good practice to list the columns in your `insert` statement explicitly (i.e. `insert into test_table( column1, column2, column3 )` rather than implicitly-- you say that `test_table` has only three columns but the error message (if it is on this line) appears to disagree.

Comment: @JustinCave, you're right about the error message and the code I provided. I've simplified the code down to just this to see if it works and still not good. I can see that line 198 is just a column being selected. How it produces this error I have not clue, since the exact same amount of columns that are in the table are being inserted by the code.

Comment: If you create a `test_table` with three columns and run just the code you posted, the procedure compiles and runs just fine.  So either you have left something out or you have simplified something so much that it no longer reproduces your issue.  As it stands, unfortunately, your question appears to be unanswerable because your test case doesn't appear to replicate your problem.

Comment: What does INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2, col3) SELECT null, null,null from dual; do ? Possibly something weird with hidden or dropped columns causing an issue, but specifying the destination columns in the appropriate order will help.

Comment: Are there triggers on the table you're inserting into?